# How do you convert a binary string like "10010010101" to a BigInteger decimal representation?

Tags: java

I know that integers have `Integer.parseInt(string, 2);` but when the value of the decimal is very large, how can we use `BigInteger` in this case?

Comment: Use `BigInteger(String val, int radix)`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Was [looking at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) really harder than posting this question?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can construct a `BigInteger` from a string which
denotes a very very large integer. This is the purpose of `BigInteger`.
If you don't use `BigInteger` it will overflow your `int` variable.

You can do this by calling.

`BigInteger b = new BigInteger(str, radix);`

where you pass in `radix = 2` or `radix = 10` or whatever
you need (seems you need 2 in your case) and `str` is the value.

Then you can use

`b.toString(radix);`

to output your `BigInteger` value in whatever radix you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger(giantBinaryString, 2);
```

[There's a constructor for that.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor BigInteger(String s)

documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 0):

For a binary integer represented as a string, use

```
BigInteger(binaryString, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this `BigInteger(binaryString, 2);`